# Aphlict not sending any messages

Tags: phabricator

We have some problem setting up Aphlict. We're using https. Both client and admin are running and show connected. No errors can be seen in Javascript console. Why does it show `20 In` but `0 Out`?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your Cluster notification looks fine.

Our running configuration looks the same:
[image]

But you should take a look at your aphlict log which is defined in the `aphlict.custom.json` config file:
[image]

Don'T forget to enable the notifications in your user profile and grant the permissions:
[image]

And then try to send a test notification while watching your log file.

Comment: I enable desktop notifications and create a test notification, but still it's not visible on the desktop, only as an app notification. Weird.

Comment: Is your browser / client connected to der aphlict port?
[Screen](http://imgur.com/a/Dcb6I)